# Two LIKE conditions but retrieving from one first then the other

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   SELECT *
   FROM address 
   WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name LIKE '% a%' LIMIT 10
```

This query retrieves `name`s that start with `a` either at the beginning `'a%'`
or in a word in the middle  `'% a%'`. How can I retrieve results from `LIKE 'a%'` first
then `LIKE '% a%'`?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `ORDER BY` clause,

```
SELECT *
FROM address
WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name LIKE '% a%' 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN name LIKE 'a%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @spencer7593 yes right `:D` I copied the wrong condition, bad. I will just remove it to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
   SELECT *
   FROM address 
   WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
   LIMIT 10
) t1
WHERE t1.name LIKE '% a%'
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to add an ORDER BY clause to your query:

```
ORDER BY IF(name LIKE 'a%',1,2)
```

---

Something like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM address 
 WHERE name LIKE 'a%' OR name LIKE '% a%'
 ORDER BY IF(name LIKE 'a%',1,2) 
 LIMIT 10
```

---

To avoid a "Using filesort" operation on large sets (i.e. LOTS of rows in address), and if you only want to return 10 rows, a more complex looking query will likely perform better, by limiting the number of rows to be sorted:

```
SELECT c.* 
  FROM ( SELECT a.*
           FROM (
                  SELECT *
                    FROM address 
                   WHERE name LIKE 'a%'
                   LIMIT 10 
                ) a
          UNION ALL
         SELECT b.*
           FROM address b
          WHERE b.name LIKE '% a%' AND b.name NOT LIKE 'a%'
          LIMIT 10
       ) c
 ORDER BY c.name LIKE 'a%' DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

A union query may be in order here.  Per MySQL documentation

To cause rows in a UNION result to consist of the sets of rows retrieved by each SELECT one after the other, select an additional column in each SELECT to use as a sort column and add an ORDER BY following the last SELECT:

```
(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
UNION
(SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;
```

So for your case something like

```
(Select *, 1 as sortcol from addresses where name like 'a%')
 Union
 (Select *, 2 as sortcol from addresses where name like '% a%')
 Order by sortcol
```

Link: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html